# Casting a superclass as one of its subclasses

Tags: swift, xcode, casting

I have a function that takes an instance of type `Being`. There are two subclasses to `Being`: `Person` and `Animal`. I want the function to recognize which of the two was passed and do something with properties specific to each subclass.

I thought this would work:

```
func fight(attacker1: Being, attacker2: Being) -> String {
    if attacker1 is Person {
        let name1 = attacker1.name as! Person //Error: Value of type Being has no member name
    } else {
        print("Its not a person")
    }
```

But it doesn't. What is the smoothest/shortest way to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: in this case why not use name in the base class Being? (as both animals and person can have name)

Comment: `attacker1.name as! Person` this is wrong, look at [V.Khambirs' Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44493238/5546312)

Comment: @giorashc They can't. It's either name or species. And depending on the class handed to the function, it needs to know which one to ask for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @V.Khambir's code works and probably is the nicer solution, it did not point out the problem of you code. You are trying to cast `.name` to a `Person`. `.name` is not a property of `attacker1`, that is why you are getting the error. What you wanted to do is cast `attacker1` to a `Person` and then access the name property.

```
func fight(attacker1: Being, attacker2: Being) -> String {
    if attacker1 is Person {
        let name1 = (attacker1 as! Person).name
    } else {
        print("Its not a person")
    }
```

Comment: Since this answer more specifically adresses my question, i have marked it as correct.

Comment: This doesn't use Swift best-practices because you're actually doing the casting twice... once in the check, then again when you want to access the name property.  The other answer on here which uses the if-let syntax is actually the one you should mark as the cast is only done once, plus you then have a strongly-typed variable of your subclass's type so no further casting is needed.

Comment: I totally agree with you! I do not like my code example either and prefer V.Khambir's code example. That's why I wrote the first sentence. However, I wanted to point out the problem of Marmelador's code.

Answer (score 6):

You should create new variable of the needed type and put on your parameter into this variable.

```
func fight(attacker1: Being, attacker2: Being) -> String {
    if let att1 = attacker1 as? Person {
        let name1 = att1.name
    } else {
        print("Its not a person")
    }
```

In this way, if attacker1 is Person, you just save this value into att1 constant and later you can use this constant as instance of the *Person* type.

Answer (score 0):

Since Being is a base class so it will not have access to any child class properties. So first of all, you have to check the type of attacker1 and attacker2. for ex: if attacker1 is of type Person then you can type cast it to an instance of type Person and then access the properties of the person object. 
Note:- Make sure to check the type first and then type cast it else it will crash.